# Knockout: several DOM elements bound to same observable

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, viewmodel

How is it possible to bind several HTML input fields to the same observable, making the observable the sum of the input fields? (the input fields are gonna take in numbers only)

I understand that I can use a ko.observable for each input field and use a ko.computed to compute the sum of the input fields, but how is this done when I'm going to have an arbitrary amount of input fields?

-Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean on "I'm going to have an arbitrary amount of input fields"? Then I guess you will have some kind collection of items so in your computed you can loop through that collection and still calculate the sum...

Comment: Well I'm gonna be able to add more input fields with the click of a button, and these new input fields are gonna be a part of the calculation for the sum.

Comment: You meant something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/RPhAD/

Comment: YES, that is EXACTLY what I mean! :D You are a good man/woman :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to have an arbitrary amount of input fields then you will probably have some kind of "item collection".

Lets call the items `ItemViewModel` where they will have some kind of `value` and the collection which stores them `items` which will be an `ko.observableArray()`

Now you just need to loop over the collection in your `ko.computed` and sum up the `value` property of the items in the collection, so you need something like this:

```
var ViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.items = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.sum = ko.computed(function (){
        var total = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.items(), function(item){
            var value = parseInt(item.value());
            if (!isNaN(value))
                total += value;
        });
        return total;
    });
};
```

You can play with this here in this [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/RPhAD/)